# initWithFireDate repeat every day

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstimer

This application is for OSX. I'm using NSTimer to run a method at a certain time of the day.

```
    NSCalendar* myCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [myCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                             fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setHour:9];
[components setMinute:30];
[components setSecond:0];
NSDate *date = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:components];

NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:date
                                      interval:0.0
                                        target:self
                                      selector:@selector(fired:)
                                      userInfo:nil
                                       repeats:NO];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

How can I get this to repeat every day?

Answer (score 1):

```
interval:86400
repeats:YES
```

Or

Add events to the users calendar with an alert

Or

Mountain lion local notifications
http://www.renssies.nl/2012/02/mountain-lion-the-new-notifications-center/

Comment: repeats:YES does't use the date it uses the interval time.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the interval. If you have fire date and interval it will fire first at fire date and then again after interval seconds.

Comment: Ok I didn't even think about setting the interval time for a day. Is this thread safe and memory safe?

Comment: Threading and memory considerations are identical when using an interval to using a fire date.

Comment: While options 2, and 3 are fine, please don’t suggest using the hard-coded seconds. Dates are hard! That’s why there are `NSCalendar`, and `NSDateComponents`. Option one will be wrong **at least** twice a year—if your users plan to travel between time zones, each direction of one such trip will be another error!

Comment: @danyowdee, good point. There are a number of issues just with the concept of using an NSTimer to repeat daily...

Answer (score -1):

`NSTimer` isn’t suited to what you want to achieve!

Instead, have a look at the [`EKReminder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKReminderClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) class, or [`NSUserNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which have been introduced in OS X 10.8.

If you have to target earlier versions of OS X, look for other options involving EKCalendar, or consider other services that handle date-math for you (IIRC, launchd has a notion of time-of-day, so there should be some other high level APIs on top of that).

There are several WWDC session videos that deal with these things — including “Events and Reminders in Event Kit”, and parts of “Internationalization Tips and Tricks” from last year.

Comment: I looked at both of those APIs, which I wish I could use. The problem is I need this to work on Snow Leopard and Lion.

Comment: Several calendar-related APIs have been deprecated with the release of 10.8. Have a look for them in Apple’s _[“Retired Documents Library”](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/)_!